# EOF in assembly using fscanf

Tags: assembly, x86, eof, scanf

I am trying to read the content of a file using `fscanf` and write that to another file. It all goes well until it reaches the end of the file when it continues to read the last word and keeps printing that to my output file.

How can I detect the **eof**? I know that I can do that using binary reading with fread but is there any way of doing this with `fscanf`?

```
.386
.model flat, stdcall

.code  
start:  
push offset read_mode       ;open the file  
push offset textFile_name   ;  
call fopen                  ;  
add esp, 8                  ;  
mov esi, eax                ;  


push offset write_mode      ;create the file
push offset dictFile_name   ;
call fopen                  ;
add esp, 8                  ;
mov edi, eax                ;


Read:  
push offset fileContent     ;read from file  
push offset formatRead  ;  
push esi                    ;  
call fscanf                 ;  
add esp, 12                 ;  



push offset fileContent     ;write to file
push offset formatWrite             ;
push edi                    ;
call fprintf                ;
add esp, 12                 ;

loop Read



push esi                    ;close files
call fclose                 ;
add esp, 4                  ;
push edi                    ;
call fclose                 ;
add esp, 4                  ;

push 0
call exit
end start
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you not checking the return value of `fscanf`???  It returns `EOF` when the end of file is reached.  `EOF` is generally -1, so (Since you didn't tag your Assembler, I will use NASM format for the example.)....

```
.Read:  
    push    ebx
    push    fmtstr
    push    esi
    call    fscanf
    add     esp, 4 * 3
    test    eax, eax
    js      .NoMore

    push    ebx
    push    fmtstr
    push    ebp
    call    fprintf
    add     esp, 4 * 3
    jmp     .Read
.NoMore:
```

...

```
extern fopen, fscanf, fprintf, fclose, fread
extern fseek, fwrite, ftell, rewind, malloc
extern free, exit, stdout

%define SEEK_END 2

global main

section .data
read_mode       db  "r", 0
write_mode      db  "w", 0
textFile_name   db  "in.txt",0
dictFile_name   db  "out.txt", 0
fmtstr          db  "%s",10 , 0

section .text
main:

    push    read_mode
    push    textFile_name 
    call    fopen
    add     esp, 4 * 2
    mov     esi, eax

    push    SEEK_END
    push    0
    push    eax
    call    fseek
    add     esp, 4 * 3

    push    esi
    call    ftell
    add     esp, 4 * 1  
    mov     edi, eax

    push    eax
    call    malloc
    add     esp, 4 * 1
    mov     ebx, eax

    push    esi
    call    rewind
    add     esp, 4 * 1

    push    write_mode
    push    dictFile_name
    call    fopen
    add     esp, 4 * 2
    mov     ebp, eax

.Read:  
    push    ebx
    push    fmtstr
    push    esi
    call    fscanf
    add     esp, 4 * 3
    test    eax, eax
    js      .NoMore

    push    ebx
    push    fmtstr
    push    ebp
    call    fprintf
    add     esp, 4 * 3
    jmp     .Read

.NoMore:        
    push    esi
    call    fclose
    add     esp, 4 * 1

    push    ebp
    call    fclose
    add     esp, 4 * 1

    push    ebx
    call    free
    add     esp, 4 * 1  

    push    0
    call    exit
    add     esp, 4 * 1
```

Wouldn't it be easier to just use `fread` and `fwrite`?

```
section .text
main:

    push    read_mode
    push    textFile_name 
    call    fopen
    add     esp, 4 * 2
    mov     esi, eax

    push    SEEK_END
    push    0
    push    eax
    call    fseek
    add     esp, 4 * 3

    push    esi
    call    ftell
    add     esp, 4 * 1  
    mov     edi, eax

    push    eax
    call    malloc
    add     esp, 4 * 1
    mov     ebx, eax

    push    esi
    call    rewind
    add     esp, 4 * 1

    push    esi
    push    edi
    push    1
    push    ebx
    call    fread
    add     esp, 4 * 4

    push    esi
    call    fclose
    add     esp, 4 * 1

    push    write_mode
    push    dictFile_name
    call    fopen
    add     esp, 4 * 2
    mov     esi, eax

    push    eax
    push    edi
    push    1
    push    ebx
    call    fwrite
    add     esp, 4 * 4

    push    esi
    call    fclose
    add     esp, 4 * 1

    push    ebx
    call    free
    add     esp, 4 * 1  

    push    0
    call    exit
    add     esp, 4 * 1
```

Error checking is left out on purpose, *you* of course should/would check the return values of those calls...

Comment: I finally got it through. Thank you for your help. btw I am using masm. Something is happening with my assembler.  

I was testing the eof as you did but it wasn't working for the fscanf so I printed the eax to the file and it was FFFFFFFF so I added this line before test eax, eax:  
xor eax, 0FFFFFFFFh  

I'm new to assembly and sometimes I get stuck by the high level programming thinking :)

Comment: Looks like it tests the -1 as FFFFFFFF and it doesn't change the flags. For freads returns 0 to eax.